# How to get the output parameter from the stored procedure using AddOutParameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the output parameter from the stored procedure.

This is my C# code :

```
public bool GetLock() // data db
{
    SqlDatabase objDB = new SqlDatabase("my conn string");

    using (DbCommand objCMD = objDB.GetStoredProcCommand("pacquirelock"))
    {
        objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@processid", DbType.Int32, (int)(LockProcesses.ReleaseWO));
        objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@description", DbType.String, GlobalConfigurationAPI.Description);
        objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@servicecenterid", DbType.Int32, jobModel_lock.branchid);
        objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@loginid", DbType.Int32, GlobalConfigurationAPI.LoginID);
        objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@owner", DbType.String, GlobalConfigurationAPI.Owner);
        objDB.AddOutParameter(objCMD, "@lockacquired", DbType.Boolean, ParameterDirection.Output);

        objDB.ExecuteNonQuery(objCMD);

        bool value = (bool)objDB.GetParameterValue(objCMD, "@lockacquired");
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[pacquirelock]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[pacquirelock]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pacquirelock]
    @processid INT,
    @description NVARCHAR(100),
    @servicecenterid INT,
    @loginid INT,
    @owner NVARCHAR(100),
    @lockacquired BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM tlock 
            WHERE islocked = 1 AND processid = @processid 
              AND (servicecenterid = @servicecenterid OR loginid = @loginid)) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @lockacquired = 0
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tlock (processid, description, servicecenterid, loginid, owner, islocked)
            VALUES (@processid, @description, @servicecenterid, @loginid, @owner, 1)

            SET @lockacquired = 1
        END 

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

It is always false, but in the db it is set to true.

The command gets executed properly - know that because it adds a new record to the table.

The `AddOutParameter` does not retrieve any parameter as an output.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Which library are you using? It looks like a homebrew veil over ADO.NET.

Comment: Microsoft.Practices.EnterPriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase

Comment: Oh, the Enterprise Bad Practices library.

Comment: It comes from assembly : #region Assembly Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Comment: @madreflection what do you suggest here to to?

Comment: For one, plan on migrating to something more acceptable in this era. Meanwhile, you're getting a `System.Data.Common.DbCommand`, so search the `Parameters` collection for one by that name and look at its `Value` property.

Comment: objDB.ExecuteNonQuery(objCMD);

                bool value = (bool)objCMD.Parameters["@lockacquired"].Value;

Comment: I tried that as well, it is always false but in db it has been set to 1(true).

Comment: As it's an output parameter, the fact that you're not getting `DBNull.Value` and thus a cast exception means it's being assigned.

Comment: do you have any idea how to get the proper value for the output parameter?

Comment: As I said, it's being assigned. If it's `0`, that's the path that's assigning it. If you want `1`, you need a state of `tlock` where that path is executed instead.

Comment: but i cast the returned value, that's the part of the code where it fails probably, could not debug that piece of code

Comment: By the time you're casting the value of the output parameter, you already have `0`. That's not the problem. The problem is in the stored procedure. Run it in SSMS with the same parameters.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. Thanks :)

Comment: The stored procedure returns true - when the insert gets executed. Thanks @madreflection